# django perform logic on fields during aggregation (instead of directly doing aggregate(Sum ('somefield')))

Tags: python, django

Code:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField()
    somenum = models.IntegerField()
```

If I want to calculate sum of all the 'somenum'(last field in above model), then I can do this:

```
queryset.aggregate(Sum('somenum'))
```

My Requirement:

sum of (enddate-startdate)(means result is num of days) excluding (saturdays, and sundays).

I can do this using normal logic, but I think aggregate or someother way is preferred.

Ways i know:

1. Loop every record of queryset, calculate num of days(excluding saturdays, sundays) for each record, and sum it during loop(like sum=0 before loop, inside loop sum += current_value; ).
2. Write signal that does this calculation(sum) when model is saved, and save calculateed value to UserProfile. When we want value, we can get it from UserProfile, but I think this process is buggy.
3. Add another field 'num_of_days' for MyModel shown above, and whenever a model is saved, the signal should perform calculation and should save that field. Then we can use queryset.aggregate(Sum('num_of_days')) .

Answer (score 1):

1. Everytime you want this data, you have to query all `MyModel` and sum in python; this is not efficient or scalable.
2. Why you would save to `UserProfile` it seems the number of days belongs in `MyModel`?
3. I think this should be the preferred method.  It is simple, elegant, easy to work on.  By doing this you put the aggregation on your database